# Magento2 : move layout to top

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-2.1

How to move minicart to toplinks block.
I want to move cart icon to top beside sign in link.

By default Mini Cart display after header links panel wrapper class.

Thanks.

Comment: have you want to move minicart in top header after header links class?

Comment: Rakesh  ...yes  i want to show it in top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep below xml code inside your theme,
`default.xml` file,

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>       
        <move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear cache.

Comment: how to move this  reference container names are different ? Rakesh

Comment: You have to just set above line in your default.xml file and see changes.

Comment: Hello, Have you checked this answer? If you stuck let me know